# Detect and mark endpoints from Canny

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to find and mark the endpoints from a canny edge map.

I was trying to do it myself by looking at points with only one neighbor but the result at this point is weird.

Is there a function in OpenCV to find endpoints?

Sample From Original Canny:

[image]

Zoomed-In Sample:

[image]

Code:

```
int neighbors;
for(int i = 1; i < (image.rows)-1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j < (image.cols)-1; j++)
    {   
        if( image.at<uchar>(i, j) == 255 )
        {
            neighbors = 0;
            for(int vx = i-1; vx <= i+1; vx++)
            {
                for(int vy = j-1; vy <= j+1; vy++)
                {
                    if(vx == i && vy == j)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if( image.at<uchar>(vx, vy) == 255 )
                        {
                            neighbors++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(neighbors == 1)
            {
                image.at<uchar>(i, j) = 80;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are sure that your white pixels are 255? make a threshold before the code to eliminate this possibility

Comment: you update single pixels to value 80 and later ask whether they are 255.

Comment: image.at<uchar>(vx, vy) should be image.at<uchar>(y, x) but this is no problem here because same range and you took the wrong inner loop ordering so in fact you should rename vx to vy and vy to vx

Comment: if you change all == 255 to != 0 it should work I guess.

Answer (score 2):

you are just overwriting your input data but your neighborhood-evaluation assumes original values. So you ask whether a neighbor has value 255 but before you might have changed a neighbors pixel value to 80 already.

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::Mat::zeros(64,64,CV_8UC1);

    cv::line(input, cv::Point(15,15), cv::Point(50,50), cv::Scalar(255));
    cv::line(input, cv::Point(50,15), cv::Point(15,50), cv::Scalar(255));

    cv::line(input, cv::Point(15,25), cv::Point(25,15), cv::Scalar(255));

    cv::line(input, cv::Point(15,15), cv::Point(10,15), cv::Scalar(255));
    cv::line(input, cv::Point(15,15), cv::Point(15,10), cv::Scalar(255));


    cv::Mat image = input.clone();

    cv::Mat output;
    cv::cvtColor(input, output, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    int neighbors;

    for(int i = 1; i < (image.rows)-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < (image.cols)-1; j++)
        {

            if( image.at<uchar>(i, j) != 0 )
            {
                neighbors = 0;

                for(int vy = i-1; vy <= i+1; vy++)
                {
                    for(int vx = j-1; vx <= j+1; vx++)
                    {
                        if(vy == i && vx == j)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if( image.at<uchar>(vy, vx) != 0 )
                            {
                                neighbors++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(neighbors == 1)
                {
                    image.at<uchar>(i, j) = 80;
                    output.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b(0,0,255);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size(1024, 1024), CV_INTER_NN);

    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imshow("output", output);
    cv::waitKey(0);

}
```

This generates this image:

[image]

and outputs this image (end points marked red):

[image]

here resized:

[image]

I also changed naming of `vx` and `vy` which were misleading.